# How can I filter javascript objects with an expression that has array in it with jmesPath?

Tags: javascript, json, expression, jmespath

I have an array of users and each user has couple of roles. The example of the array is shown below.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: 'john',
        roles: [
            {id: 500, name: 'Admin'},
            {id: 501, name: 'Owner'}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: 'joe',
        roles: [
            {id: 500, name: 'Admin'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        username: 'june',
        roles: [
            {id: 502, name: 'User'},
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get all the users who have an *Admin* role by using jmesPath. I've tried `[?roles[].name=='Admin']` but this is giving a `null` value. Is is possible to do this with jmesPath, and if yes can you give me an expression for this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played a little with this example and your data

http://jmespath.org/examples.html#filtering-and-selecting-nested-data

I made it work with this expression

```
[?roles[?name=='Admin']]
```

Comment: This actually works, but I can't understand your query. Can you please explain it here?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the same result with plain JavaScript using:

Assuming your array is stored on var users = [...].

```
users.filter((i)=> i.roles.some((s) => s.name === "Admin"))
```

You can see [this sample with jsBin](https://jsbin.com/lelira/edit?js,console)